# Jquery hover show and hide visibility issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having a slight problem with my hover jquery show and hide function i have implemented. [click here for site][1]When i apply `visibility: hidden;` to my CSS, this div `.hover-hide` does not display. However when i remove the css property `visibility: hidden;` the hover show and hide function works once you have hovered over the div `.hover-hide`. Does anyone know what i am doing wrong. Below is a snippet of my code:

html

```
<figure class="tint">
        <div class="carousel-col-copy hover-hide">
        <h1>lee vintage</h1>
        <div class="col-copy-passage col-copy-boarder">
        <p>With prints inspired by the abstract artists Blinky Palermo and Robert Mangold, lee vintage presents bold pieces from their SS13 collection</p>
        </div>
        </div>
    <img src="timthumb/timthumb.php?src=img/20.jpg&w=450&h=530&zc=1&q=100&a=0" class="slider-img grid-img">
    </figure>


$(".tint").hover(function(){
        $('.hover-hide').removeClass('hidden');
        },function(){
            $('.hover-hide').addClass('hidden');
        });
```

Comment: Works fine here - http://jsfiddle.net/RUUAp/

Comment: @Zenith the text is not meant to display unless you hover over the image

Comment: @NewBoy check this. http://jsfiddle.net/5LkJs/ or http://jsfiddle.net/F9pSt/

Comment: @NewBoy - Wouldn't adding the hidden class to your div below the figure accomplish what you want?

Comment: @PSCoder thanks, type your answer up and i'll accept it. I used your method

Comment: @NewBoy Great it worked, doing now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:-

### http://jsfiddle.net/DhQjk/

### css

```
.hidden { visibility:hidden; }
```

### Html

Add `hidden` class to your dynamic content initially.

```
 <div class="carousel-col-copy hover-hide hidden">
```

### JS

Use `.toggle()` on hover.

```
$(".tint").hover(function(){
        $('.hover-hide').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

[Ref .toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Answer (score 2):

Use `display:none` and jQuery's built in functions `.show()` and `.hide()` instead.

CSS

```
.hover-hide{
   display:none;
}
```

jQUery

```
$(".tint").hover(function(){
    $('.hover-hide').show();
},function(){
    $('.hover-hide').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it just with css.

```
.hover-hide {
    display: none;
}
.tint:hover .hover-hide {
    display: block;
}
```

**[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RUUAp/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

I just don't getting why everybody want's to use jquery for this.
The better solution is to use CSS like this one:

```
.tint .hover-hide {
  display:none;
}
.tint:hover .hover-hide {
  display:block;
}
```

That's all. Nothing more needed to do any coding.

Comment: as for fade you can use transition effects

Comment: my first attempt was the css approach but it did not work. This way i attempted JS